# How do I add value to currency?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to add value to currency in python. I'm using locale.currency to create the format and I have it in a variable. I want to print the variable + value to add to make a new value.

```
import locale
locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, '' )
'English_United States.1252'
while True:
    print("Welcome! Get ur pet here!")
    pet = input("Would you like a dog, cat, or fish:").lower()
    d = ("           __ \n      (___()'`;\n      /,    /` \n      \\\\'--\\\  ")
    money = (locale.currency( 25 ))
    if pet == "dog":
        print(money)  #I've done (money + 10) There is no error message, but 
                       #I want it to add 10 to 25 and it doesn't do that.
        print(d)
```

Comment: I can't actually find a suitable duplicate target for this.

Comment: In case you were wondering why you got downvotes, it's probably because you didn't show us the error, and you didn't create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`local.curency` returns a string. You can't *add value to it*.

You must store the money as an integer and format it with `local.curency` only when you print it.

```
money = 25
if pet == "dog":
    print(locale.currency(money+10))
    print(d)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: don't forget to mark the question as solved if your problem is fixed.